# Gradient of squared euclidean norm

Tags: vector-analysis

For a given: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

I am trying to calculate the gradient of:

$$f(x) := \frac{1}{2}\left\|{A^T x}\right\|_2^2 - b^Tx.$$

Therefore I wrote $f$ like this:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\left(A_{.,i}x\right)^2 - b_i^T x_i\right),$$

where $A_{.,i}$ denotes column $i$ of matrix $A$. 
After this I only get completely wrong results. 
Can anybody tell me how to continue or where I got wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I take it $x$ is an $m\times 1$ vector? What are the dimensions of $b?$

Comment: First of all, what has gone wrong is perhaps what the square actually means in the sum (square of vector)? Secondly, try to focus on the partial derivative with respect to $i$. Can you find out how $x_i$ appears in the matrix product?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes it is. The problem is actually the Lagrangian dual of
$\underset{w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\text{min }} \frac{1}{2}||w||^2_2 \text{    s.t.   } A w = b$  with $||A_{i,.}||_2=1$ für $i=1,2,\dots,m$ and to recover the primal solution $w=A^Tx$ is used.